Increase in random upvotes on old answers over the last months
So I got my first random upvote on an old answer in May which was cool, but this(2 upvotes, not the accepted answer) is not the answer I would have expected to get that.
Then I got another one in June, 2 more in July and now 5 in August, 2 of them today! It's spread out over months and the answers had at least 2 upvotes before. Also, with one exception, they aren't highly upvoted nor is their content connected and they are also not really my best work. It doesn't appear to fit with the answers here at all: I get surges of upvotes, and they are lumpy in time. Is this because the site is surfacing my questions all at once, or do I have a stalker/superfan?
Obviously I'm assuming bots, but does anyone actually know or have an informed guess about what is going on?

Maybe somebody appreciates your answers. :-)

One person makes no sense to me but I did actually write almost half my answers in the last year, so maybe this is just seasonality that I never noticed before ¯\(ツ)/¯

I experienced the same thing in the last few days. In addition, like some other people, I recently lost reputation over serial voting reversed. So now when my answers get a series of upvotes apparently out of nowhere, my reaction is to be a bit more skeptical than I used to (not too skeptical though: upvoting old answers is something I do quite often myself). There's nothing much I can do about serial voting anyway so I don't really worry about the issue. I'd be much more worried if I got downvotes due to incorrect or bad answers.

This could be an example of Name of a particular post-hoc statistical fallacy and it is risky to overthink it. In any case many of the greater works are not receiving the rightful attention in terms of votes. So seemingly random votes on minor posts, they are just like random noise that scatters onto all of your posts at once (not taking into account the quality).

It may well be that SE shows old threads at the top of the page once in a while. I believe this at least happens for threads with answers that have zero upvotes. Perhaps this also happens sometimes for answers with nonzero upvotes?


Obviously I'm assuming bots, but does anyone actually know or have an informed guess about what is going on?

It's premature to jump to a conclusion such as this.
There is nothing wrong in getting upvotes from some arbitrary posts, at arbitrary times of the year. There is nothing to dissect here.
It's not necessary that the "best" content would be upvoted most, though it should. If someone gets helpful information even from a mediocre post, then they should upvote it, irrespective of its mediocrity on a certain scale. Again, there is nothing wrong in that. What matters is whether the post is helpful or not.
If there is any event that might arise from serial upvoting or sock puppetry or any other unhealthy mechanisms, it's imperative that the system has the ability to safeguard and undo such actions one way or another.
For instance, have a look at the recent thread: Serial voting reversed.

This is a little unsatisfying. I was perfectly happy with one or two a month, but five? I'm apparently not the only one who noticed an increase in activity, see J-J-J here and sextus empiricus in the serial voting thread. I guess we will se if the "system" detects anything.
